# facebook auth dialog 2-step process

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I'm trying to set up the auth dialog of my facebook app to only have 1 step where the user accepts permissions, but for some reason, facebook insists on createing a two step process.

In the auth dialog panel I have set user permissions to user_photos and extended to publish_stream. The dialog however ONLY shows permissions for user_photos

this means, that when the user goes to my site, which also checks for permissions they're being asked to permit publish_stream also. Why doesn't the auth dialog take both of the permissions? Isn't that the whole point of being able to write it? If i delete user_photos THEN the dialog will show the publish_stream request too, but then of course my site will ask for user_photos.

Is this a bug or behaviour by design, because I really don't get why a possible 1-step auth is made 2 step and I've seen it one step with much more permissions in other apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a bug, it's a feature: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#permissions

User may accept basic permissions, but decline 1 or more extended permissions.

Comment: thank you. But why would any developer want to use that? Forcing the user to click yes twice is pretty bad design IMO.

Comment: well, I believe every developer has own reason to use it, or not to use it. It was designed this way ages ago: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ and it is still working, making good ROI. I don't see why this design is bad, since it generates revenue.